# How can I access methods of a component using ref in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to access a component method using `createRef()` however i am getting `TypeError: modalRef.current is null` error back.

I never used refs before so if its wrong guide the way how to achieve what I am trying to do.

this is my try

```
const parent = () => {
  const modalRef = createRef();
  const onBtnClick = () => {
   modalRef.current.upadeState();
  }
  return(
  <div>
   <button onclick={onBtnClick}>bro</button>
    <Modal ref={modalRef} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

Modal

```
export default Modal = () => {
  const upadeState = () => {
   console.log('It works fam');
   }
  return(
  <div>
    bro we here
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace `createRef()` with `useRef()` ?

Comment: check the accepted answer fam @TheKNVB

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For calling Child Component method from parent component in hooks we are using [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) and [React.useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hooks from React.

Here is an example to call the child method.

**Child.js**

```
import React from "react";
const { forwardRef, useState, useImperativeHandle } = React;

// We need to wrap component in `forwardRef` in order to gain
// access to the ref object that is assigned using the `ref` prop.
// This ref is passed as the second parameter to the function component.
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const getAlert = () => {
    alert("getAlert from Child");
    setState(state => state + 1)
  };

  // The component instance will be extended
  // with whatever you return from the callback passed
  // as the second argument
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getAlert,
  }));

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Count {state}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => getAlert()}>Click Child</button>
      <br />
    </>
  );
});
```

**Parent.js**

```
import React from "react";
const { useRef } = React;

export const Parent = () => {
  // In order to gain access to the child component instance,
  // you need to assign it to a `ref`, so we call `useRef()` to get one
  const childRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button onClick={() => childRef.current.getAlert()}>Click Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child component is rendered and a ref is created using [React.useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) named childRef. The button we created in the parent component is now used to call the child component function `childRef.current.getAlert();`